# Updating table's rows with operations between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make a query to avoid having to use too much php. I would like to update **world1**'s rows (wood, wheat, gold, meat) by adding to these values the values of the table **upgrading**. This is as far as I could get :

```
SELECT wood_cancel, wheat_cancel, gold_cancel, meat_cancel FROM upgrading WHERE world = 'world1' AND player_id = 190 AND city_id = 1 AND cancel_id = 'cancel_wood_rate_1';
UPDATE world1 SET wood = wood + wood_cancel, wheat = wheat + wheat_cancel, gold = gold + gold_cancel, meat = meat + meat_cancel WHERE player_id = 190 AND city_id = 1;
DELETE FROM upgrading WHERE world = 'world1' AND player_id = 190 AND city_id = 1 AND cancel_id = 'cancel_wood_rate_1'SELECT wood_cancel, wheat_cancel, gold_cancel, meat_cancel FROM upgrading WHERE world = 'world1' AND player_id = 190 AND city_id = 1 AND cancel_id = 'cancel_wood_rate_1';
```

The SQL error message says  wood_cancel, wheat_cancel, gold_cancel and meat_cancel can't be found. How should I proceed ?

Do I need to use some kind of JOIN ? If so, how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do UPDATE with JOIN with similar syntax as doing a JOIN when SELECTing like this:

```
UPDATE world1 w INNER JOIN upgrading u 
ON w.player_id = u.player_id AND w.city_id = u.city_id
SET w.wood = w.wood + u.wood_cancel
WHERE u.world = 'world1' AND u.player_id = 190
AND u.city_id = 1 AND u.cancel_id = 'cancel_wood_rate_1';

DELETE FROM upgrading 
WHERE world = 'world1' AND player_id = 190 
AND city_id = 1 AND cancel_id = 'cancel_wood_rate_1';
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/242f8/2

Answer (score 0):

The reason this error occurs is because values from one statement do not carry over to other statements without a `JOIN` or similar. i.e. MySQL does not understand that `wood_cancel` came from the previous `SELECT` statement.

MySQL does have the concept of [user-defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html). With this type of method, you only have to insert the values from PHP at the beginning.

Personally I would shift all the logic into PHP so that there is no logic occuring at the database level.

*Note: Untested.*

```sql
SET @world = 'world1'
    @player_id = 190, 
    @city_id = 1, 
    @cancel_id = 'cancel_wood_rate_1',
    @wood_cancel = 0,
    @wheat_cancel = 0,
    @gold_cancel = 0,
    @meat_cancel = 0

SELECT 
    @wood_cancel := wood_cancel, @wheat_cancel := wheat_cancel, @gold_cancel := gold_cancel, @meat_cancel := meat_cancel
FROM 
    upgrading 
WHERE 
    world = @world
AND player_id = @player_id 
AND city_id = @city_id
AND cancel_id = @cancel_id;

UPDATE 
    world1 
SET 
    wood = wood + @wood_cancel, 
    wheat = wheat + @wheat_cancel, 
    gold = gold + @gold_cancel, 
    meat = meat + @meat_cancel 
WHERE 
    player_id = @player_id 
AND city_id = @city_id;

DELETE FROM 
    upgrading 
WHERE 
    world = @world 
AND player_id = @player_id 
AND city_id = @city_id
AND cancel_id = @cancel_id;
```